# Update data in a JsonField django

Tags: python, json, django, django-jsonfield

I want to update a json object that is in a jsonfield in django, i am having a problem updating the data.

My model looks like this
https://codeshare.io/Gbeonj

My json looks like this
https://codeshare.io/5obDPX

so basicly the json has wrong data , instead of "NATIONAL ID Card" it has "NATIONAL ID" so i want to update this json object to have the right data.
here is what am talking about

```
"info": {
        "mobilePhone": "", 
        "firstName": "david", 
        "tags": [], 
        "middleName": "mirale", 
        "gender": "Male", 
        "documentType": "NATIONAL ID", 
        "beneficiary": false, 
        "dateOfBirth": "1995-03-04T08:01:42.165Z", 
        "documentNumber": "519011016721", 
        "dateOfBirthExact": false, 
        "role": "Child", 
        "lastName": "ABSURG0058", 
        "recipient": "Alternate", 
        "homePhone": ""
      },
```

the  `"documentType": "NATIONAL ID",` should be "NATIONAL ID Card"

i am using the following script to update the json object in the server.

```
import django
django.setup()

import sys
reload(sys)    # to re-enable sys.setdefaultencoding()
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')


import json
from django.db import transaction
from maidea.apps.mobile.models import MobileDocument


office = 'sa_de'

#we fetch all the mobile documents from that have failed
uploads = MobileDocument.objects.filter(
    status=MobileDocument.ERROR,
    mobile_upload__office__slug=office
)

print('Number of uploads fetched: %d' %(uploads.count()))

with transaction.atomic():
    for upload in uploads:
        for member in upload.data['members']:
            try:
                doc_type_value = member['info'].get('documentType')
            except:
                doc_type_value = None
            if doc_type_value == 'NATIONAL ID':
          doc_type_value = doc_type_value.replace('NATIONAL ID', 'NATIONAL ID Card')
          assert doc_type_value == 'NATIONAL ID Card'
                  upload.save()
```

The problem is that this object is not been updated kindly what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have validated the `doc_type_value` you are not setting it back into the `upload` object, you need to update the `upload` object:

```
for upload in uploads:
    data = upload.data
    updated_members = []
    for member in data['members']:
        try:
            doc_type_value = member['info'].get('documentType')
        except KeyError:
            pass
        else:
            if doc_type_value == 'NATIONAL ID':
                doc_type_value = 'NATIONAL ID Card'
                member['info']['documentType'] = doc_type_value
        updated_members.append(member)

    data['members'] = updated_members
    upload.data = data
    upload.save()
```